# Cannot establish many to many relationship in my model

Tags: powerbi

I am using PowerBI Desktop September 2019 release and I have two tables :

Employee
Country
I want to establish Many to many relationship between the two tables but I can't find (it is not detected) :

[image]

When I want to desactivate Composite Model in the features, I can't find the Preview features in GLOBAL :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

are you using the Power BI Desktop Report Server? as the preview features wouldnt be available in there

If you could show more information about your tables that would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case, you are  deploying to a `Power BI Report Server` instead of to `Powerbi Desktop`. 
`Power BI Report Server` does not support many to many relationships yet, that is currently only supported in the cloud environment.
You can know the difference by checking this [article](http://powerbiforum.blogspot.com/2018/07/powerbi-desktop-vs-powerbi-services.html).